# Why doesn't my CSS override bootstrap 5 styles?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to change the color of the background and text for my navbar. When I use a class name that I chose or one from Bootstrap5 it doesn't override the style.

HTML file

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Assests/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Assests/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
```

CSS file

```
.navbar {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Tried switching order of css and BS5 scripts. That just made everything worse. I also tried to add my own class names.

Comment: `navbar` is a Bootstrap class name isn't it? If you inspect the element in the Dev Tools, what styles does it show are attached to the `.navbar` element?